# Does iPhone support SSE2?

Tags: iphone, ios, sse

There are so many statements in my code containing __m128i,_mm_loadu_si128,_mm_avg_epu8 and many more. This things work on Mac but fails to compile in ios. What are the replacements for these in IOS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SSE is an Intel technology that is not available on the iOS devices' ARM chips. Have a look at the [Accelerate framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html) for Apple's multi-platform API for these types of calculations.

The ARM architecture also provides its own SIMD (single instruction multiple data) instruction set called [NEON](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/neon.php), which is available on armv7 devices (iPhone 3GS and above).

Comment: Can you give some idea or link to learn how to use these and code.